# Geodesics on the torus

Tags: geometry, differential-geometry, manifolds

<sup>[This is a follow-up to my question [Is there a Möbius torus?](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/217513/is-there-a-mobius-torus)]</sup>

Mark L. Irons' paper [The Curvature and Geodesics of the Torus](http://www2.rdrop.com/~half/math/torus/torus.geodesics.pdf) gives a concise overview of the [geodesics](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Geodesic) on the torus:

- There are five clear-cut families of geodesics.
- Most of the geodesics are "chaotic": aperiodic and covering either the entire surface - by spiraling endlessly around the torus - or substantial parts of it.
- Some of the geodesics are "boring": the meridians, the inner and the outer equator
- A few of them are "æsthetically pleasing": returning to their starting point after just a few circuits around the z axis

What I tried to ask in my [previous question](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/217513/is-there-a-mobius-torus):

> Can the structure of geodesics on the torus change drastically when
>   twisting the "hose" before gluing its ends?

For example: There might be no equator anymore because after twisting the (two) equators lost their "ends".

<sup>[I also posted this question at [MO](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/110484/geodesics-on-a-twisted-torus).]</sup>

Comment: Topologically, the result of a simple twist will again be a torus. And a torus has an equator, and all the different classes of geodesics. However, the geodesics of the new torus are usually unrelated to those of the original torus: the twist introduced a bending to the whole metric, and would cause the old metric to become disconontinuous along the seam. So I cannot think of a way to reasonably answer this question.

Comment: Is there really a seam? And is there a seam in the Möbius strip? And is there a discontinuity?

Comment: If you claim that equators lost their “ends”, then in that interpretation there is a seam, where things that used to be geodesics in the untwisted gluing are geodesics no more. Usually I'd say there is no seam in the Möbius strip, but with that same argument I'd say a twisted torus is just the same as an untwisted torus. The argument here is that you concentrate on the topology of the thing up front, and obtain a compatible metric from that topology alone, without regard to any metric the thing might have had before twisting and/or gluing operations.

Comment: The Villarceau Circle, not a boring case but not a geodesic.

Answer (score 4):

My article directly compares the spectrum of closed geodesics on the flat torus to the normal torus:
http://www34.homepage.villanova.edu/robert.jantzen/notes/torus/
By thinking like a physicist, you can get a much better picture of this problem.

Answer (score 0):

Lets say the Torus was painted with stripes parallell to the long axis before the twist. If the twist was just enough to put the beginning of the first line and the end of the second line together, you would get one continuous line all the way, I Think. Except if the twist was 180 degrees (or some multiple thereof), and there was an even number of lines, in which case you would get two (or pairs) of continous lines, each with half of the lines in a row.

Answer (score 0):

If the twisting angle is some rational number of full $2\pi$ twists, say $\frac pq$ revolutions, $p,q\in\bf \mathbb{Z}\space\backslash \left\{0\right\}$, then your equator ends will reconnect together after exactly $\frac qp$ full revolutions.

If it's irrational number of full-twists, then the resulting equator orbit will cover the whole torus space, and have Hausdorff dimension two, instead of ordinary one.

Based on irrational rotation dynamical systems.